# Dynamic font sizing

Tags: javascript

I have a div tag inside a TD element that must be under a certain size (in characaters). This is the code I have setup to shrink the font size to maintain the width.

I wondered if it would be possible to have it look at the max characters, `60` in this case, then for every `10` characters above `60`, it would reduce to font size by `.1em`.

**NOTE:** I am using the numbers `10` and `.1` as examples. I would of course play with the two numbers to achieve exactly what I need.

This the code I have right now: http://jsfiddle.net/Hn46H/31/.

A short version is:

```
var varCarrier1 = document.getElementById('DivCarrier1').innerHTML;

// Check Carrier 1 length to determine the font size.

if (varCarrier1.length >= 60) {
    DIVCarrier1.style.fontSize = ".55em";
}

if (varCarrier1.length >= 97) {
    DIVCarrier1.style.fontSize = ".45em";
}
```